# Validate the Aspect is applied at the class level NOT the method level

Tags: postsharp

I have an OnMethodBoundaryAspect and within the CompileTimeValidate method I'd like to verify that the Aspect attribute is being applied at the class level.
example:

```
    [MyCustomAspect]
    public class SomeClass
    {
    ...
```

I wouldn't like this to throw a compilation error. 
example:

```
    public class SomeClass
    {
        [MyCustomAspect]
        public void SomeMethod() {
        ...
```

How can I detect where my Aspect attribute is being applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moment when `CompileTimeValidate` method executes is already too late to validate the attribute application. The "attribute multicasting" step runs first, and it will propagate the method level aspect applied on a class to the class methods, removing the original attribute at the same time.

To validate the attribute application you can configure the valid targets with `[AttributeUsage]`.

```
[Serializable]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class MyCustomAspect : MethodLevelAspect
{
    // ...
}
```